# How to access EngineYard database from local machine?

Tags: mysql, database, cloud, engineyard

I have created a Rails application and hosted it on EngineYard. Now I want to manually insert one record into my database.[Database: MYSQL]

How can I access EngineYard's database from my local machine?

P.S: I have came across this [article](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21009887-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel) and I can't infer proper explanation from that. I have even searched for video tutorials and can't find any. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast I got the answer for my question after spending a lot of time on this and getting support from EngineYard team.

1. First you need to create a local SSH Key Pair by following [this](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/20996846-Set-up-SSH-keys) article.
2. Next you need to add that SSH Key (something like id_rsa.pub or id_dsa.pub) at https://cloud.engineyard.com/keypairs
3. Then you need to execute this command in your local terminal
   `ssh deploy@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

   where `deploy` is the common and default username for your database and `ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com` is your hostname